# How can I trigger a table and update the same table?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I'm doing a trigger that when I update a table, the same table updates a field.
The trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_user
AFTER UPDATE
ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.totalPoints > 0 AND NEW.totalPoints < 200)  
    THEN
        updateUser("rank 1", NEW.ID);  
    ELSEIF (NEW.totalPoints > 200 AND NEW.totalPoints < 400)  
    THEN
        updateUser("rank 2", NEW.ID);
    END IF;
END;
```

and the procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateUser(newRank VARCHAR(100), IDUser INT)
BEGIN
  UPDATE users SET rank = newRank WHERE ID = IDUser;
END;
```

The error I have is when create the procedure:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Hey! Here's a reason why you shouldn't call functions from triggers: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-trigger

Comment: Instead of `updateUser("rank 1", NEW.ID);` you can just use `SET NEW.rank = 'rank 1';`

Comment: I thik you should use delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BEFORE` update trigger.  However, you can't really use the procedure for this purpose:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_user BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.totalPoints > 0 AND NEW.totalPoints < 200)  
    THEN
        SET NEW.rank = 'rank 1';
    ELSEIF (NEW.totalPoints > 200 AND NEW.totalPoints < 400)  
    THEN
        SET NEW.rank = 'rank 2';
    END IF;
END;
```

A stored procedure that  modifies the data is going to be difficult to use in a trigger.

EDIT:

If you express this as:

```
SET NEW.RANK = (CASE WHEN NEW.totalPoints > 0 AND NEW.totalPoints < 200
                     THEN 'rank 1'
                     WHEN NEW.totalPoints > 200 AND NEW.totalPoints < 400
                     THEN 'rank 2'
                     ELSE NEW.RANK
                END);
```

With no `IF` logic at all.

Comment: I tried this but the error is the same, near '' at line 6

Answer (score 0):

Lets try with using delimiters

```
DELIMITER $$    
    CREATE TRIGGER update_user AFTER UPDATE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.totalPoints > 0 AND NEW.totalPoints < 200)  
        THEN
            SET NEW.rank = 'rank 1';
        ELSEIF (NEW.totalPoints > 200 AND NEW.totalPoints < 400)  
        THEN
            SET NEW.rank = 'rank 2';
        END IF;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No, it says just ERROR

Comment: Ok.Thats a bit confusing.We will try.If u find the answer yourself , do tell us what was the problem